# Implementing Simulation application using AKKA

Tags: scala, docker, routes, akka, simulation

I am using akka actors to implement a simulation application with central controller (represented by an instance of Actor1), set of entities (represented by instances of Actor2) that negotiate with each other and with the surrounding environment to take decisions and then behaviors, and the simulation environment which is composed of a set of squared areas (represented by set of instances of Actor3).

I am confused about how can I implement the messaging technique between the controller, the simulation entities, and the environment squares. I am investigating the `Routing` and the `EventBus` utilities in Akka. I am confused about which one is suitable to my scenarios. Could you have any ideas?

The first version of the application is running on a single machine, but later, I am going to run it distributed may be by using Docker for example !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between `Routing` and `EventBus` is the responsible party for Actor failure monitoring.  Should the Controller, Actor1, monitor the life cycle of the various Actor2 and Actor3 instances (e.g. contain the logic to handle a death of an Actor)?

If the answer is yes, then Actor1 should use it's context to spawn off Actor2 & Actor3 children and using routing to send the children messages.

If, on the other hand, the Controller is not responsible for children then the Actor2 & Actor3 instances should be created outside of Actor1 and Actor1 should message them with EventBus.

Based on your comment "...but later, I am going to run it distributed..." I would suggest **not** making Controller responsible for Actor2 & Actor3 life cycles and using EventBus.

Comment: Thanks, @Ramon, for this accurate answer.

Comment: In case of using EventBus, how can we handle broadcasting messages to all (e.g. time unit message) and negotiation messages between two actors. Is it semantically accepted by using EventBus.

Comment: @Manar You are welcome.  Yes, the EventBus has a typical publish/subscribe mechanism.  The `ActorSystem.evenStream` method returns an `akka.event.EventStream`.  That stream can handle multiple "Channels" routing different message types to different subscriber sets.  Happy hacking.